# Hibernate left join using with

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join

Reading the hibernate documentation, you find the following on Left Joins [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

Assume the following setup.

```
Cat1
 Kitten1 (bodyWeight:11.0)
 Kitten2 (bodyWeight:12,5)

Cat2 
 Kitten3 (bodyWeight:17.1)
 Kitten4 (bodyWeight:5,2)

Cat3
```

Given the setup, will the query above give us the following result?

```
Cat1
 Kitten1 (bodyWeight:11.0)
 Kitten2 (bodyWeight:12,5)

Cat2 
 Kitten3 (bodyWeight:17.1)
 ...

Cat3
```

Answer (score 0):

yes and if there was another cat

```
Cat4
 Kitten1 (bodyWeight:1.0)
 Kitten2 (bodyWeight:2,5)
```

Cat4 would also be returned, but with no kittens